# Find highest values whose cumulative sum reaches limit

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I have the following type of dataframe representing the volume of a financial product  that each company has issued every year, as well as the percentage of total issuance these volumes represent for each year.

```
  year           company       Volume     Volume Year          %
1 2013            AWK      347902000    21927606761     0.015865936
2 2013            DAR      177977000    21927606761     0.008116572
3 2013            DTC      615627000    21927606761     0.028075431
4 2013            GMT      538456000    21927606761     0.024556077
5 2013            CLW      407497000    21927606761     0.018583743
6 2013            AYI       31970000    21927606761     0.001457979
```

For each year, I want to select the largest issuing companies that together represent 70% of total market volume.

I can do this manually, but I'm looking for a formula I can easily apply to my large datasets, and that I can use a lot in the future !

Comment: Please try writing the code yourself, then show us where you got stuck. Just break it down into subproblems. First, how would you add a new column *PctVol* showing each company's volume as % of total market volume, for that year? Next, sort the dataframe by year then by decreasing order on *PctVol*. etc.

Comment: @ smci The '%' row represents each company's volume as % of total market volume for that year. Sure, I can do this manually for each year, I'm looking for a faster formula, because my dataset is quite large, and I will have to do the same procedure quite a lot in the future !

Comment: RomainBerrou: there's nothing manual about it: if you had simply followed my hints, you would very quickly have arrived at the need for `cumsum(PctVol)`. I didn't want to give you all the hints at once since [officially we're not supposed to spoonfeed users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353968/should-we-spoonfeed-the-users). You really are supposed to try writing a line or three of code before posting the question, at minimum that helps you frame the question in terms of specific a code issue (not just "Here's my spec").

Comment: Smci: Didn't mean to offend you. I have written quite a few lines of code before making the decision of asking online, but none really made sense, so I took the decision not to post any. But I understand your point, and won't do it again, especially if it implies getting condescending feedback in return.

Comment: Welcome to SO and once you start answering questions, you are likely to develop a newfound empathy for those users.

Comment: Also, R [base package](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/00Index.html) has all sorts of rich functions (e.g. `cumsum/cumprod`), and the ones that aren't vectorized can be vectorized with `apply`. Have a look through the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first sort by year and Volume, then make a `cumsum` per year using `ave` and then select those which are below 70% like:

```
tt  <- read.table(header=T, text="year           company       Volume     VolumeYear          p
2013            AWK      347902000    21927606761     0.015865936
2013            DAR      177977000    21927606761     0.008116572
2013            DTC      615627000    21927606761     0.028075431
2013            GMT      538456000    21927606761     0.024556077
2013            CLW      407497000    21927606761     0.018583743
2013            AYI       31970000    21927606761     0.001457979")

tt <- tt[with(tt, order(year, -Volume)),]
tt$pc  <- with(tt, ave(p, year, FUN=cumsum))
tt[tt$pc <= .7, c("year","company")]
```

Answer (score 1):

using **dplyr** library (and assuming your data.frame is `DF`):

```r
library(dplyr)

trimmed_DF = DF %>% 
   mutate(percentage = Volume/VolumeYear) %>%    # you already have this column, though.
   group_by(year) %>% 
   mutate(new_col = cumsum(percentage)) %>%
   filter(new_col > 0.30)                        # 0.3 = 1 - 0.7
```